# Android + JUnit + Espresso Class not found in different directory

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, junit, android-espresso

Have issue. I have project with tests, but I need create own tests in different directory. So when I run my test from my directory I have error:

> Class not found: "tests.FirstTest"

But when I move this class to other directory (androidTest which was created before) it's works fine. Can anyone help me?

Also If I try to rename androidTest category I have error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.